# What is the difference between Maxwell distribution and Boltzmann distribution?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, terminology

I am learning Physical Chemistry now. And on the print professor uploaded was a sentence "Compare Maxwell distribution with the Boltzmann distribution"

What I know is only -mv^2/kT is written in Maxwell distribution and -E/kT is written in Boltzmann distribution. What does this mean?

Answer (score 7):

First of all, review what you learnt, if the professor asked you for this he probably explained it somewhere! When you are done, here's the rest of the answer:

Briefly, Maxwell's distribution is a "sub-part" of Boltzmann's for which we focus only on the velocity distribution of the particles.

As you probably know, the state of the sistem is defined by its position $(x, y, z)$ and its velocity $(v_x, v_y, v_z)$ with magnitude (speed) $v=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}$.

Boltzmann's distribution is the probability distribution of the *state* of the system, i.e. $P_B(x, y, z, v_x, v_y, v_z)dx dy dz dv_x dv_y dv_z$ is the probability of finding a particle in a given position with a given speed. Thus it depends on both the *position* and the *velocity* of the system.

If we are only interested in the velocities of the system, we can obtain Maxwell's distribution $P_M$ from Boltzmann's as 
$$P_M(v_x, v_y, v_z) =\int dx dy dz\; P_B(x, y, z, v_x, v_y, v_z)$$
i.e. by summing (integrating) over all possible positions.

Since in general (for systems which are normal enough) we can write the energy $E$ as a sum of the kinetic energy $K(v_x, v_y, v_z)={1\over 2}mv^2$ (related to the velocity/speed) and of the interaction potential $U(x, y, z)$, so that $E=K+U$, we get that (neglecting pre-factors):
$$P_B(x, y, z, v_x, v_y, v_z)\propto e^{-E/kT} = e^{-K(v_x, v_y, v_z)/kT}e^{-U(x, y, z)/kT}$$
and from the definition above, integrating over all possible positions

$$P_M(v_x, v_y, v_z) \propto \int dx dy dz\; e^{-{1\over 2}mv^2/kT}e^{-U(x, y, z)/kT} = e^{-{1\over 2}mv^2/kT} \int dx dy dz\; e^{-U(x, y, z)/kT}  =  Ae^{-{1\over 2}mv^2/kT} $$ where $A$ is a constant coming from the integration over all positions. And this is what we call a Maxwell distribution (which can also be derived in other ways, of course, but this one is the one that links it with Boltzmann's).

EDIT: often, when one talks about Boltzmann's distribution, he or she is referring to the probability distribution $\rho(x, y, z)$ of the positions only (e.g. in an harmonic or gravitational potential). Separating the position and velocity parts is (formally) easy when they are not coupled as in the example above, i.e. $U$ does not depend on the velocity and $K$ does not depend on the position, so that, doing the opposite of what we did above i.e. integrating over the veocities:

$$\rho(x, y, z)\propto  \int dv_x dv_y dv_z\; e^{-{1\over 2}mv^2/kT}e^{-U(x, y, z)/kT} = Be^{-U(x, y, z)/kT} $$

where $B$ contains the result of the integration and all the constant factors. Often one refers to $\rho$ as Boltzmann's distribution.

Comment: this is very clear and very useful, thanks for taking the time to spell it all out.

Comment: no problem, I also edited a little bit to improve the answer.